# Duplicate row while creating index

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create unique index `uind` on 

`report_datanew6(service_description,host_name,state,event_type,timestamp)`
```

I ran this query and it gives an error.

> Error : [ Err] 1062 - Duplicate field ' 1A_Incomer -
>   06_ELP_RL_VEP_01_PLC - 2-701-1399377282 ' for key ' Uind '

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Either remove duplicate values first, or create a regular, non-unique index.

Comment: How can we remove duplicate value?

Comment: First find them using GROUP BY column HAVING count(*) > 1, then update/delete depending in what you want. Are you sure you really need a unique index? Describe why!